# How to compile C++ program by command line on Mac

Tags: xcode, gcc, g++, clang

I used to use `Xcode` to build and run `C++` program.

I use command line to compile the same source code in my `Xcode` project.

Compiling a individual `.cpp` file is OK.

Compiling more complicated project(more than one file) is NOT OK.

I have tried `gcc`, `g++`, `clang`, `clang++`.

The main problem is undefined symbol.

Could you show how to compile complicated project (more than one file) by command line?

Comment: You should probably read some documentation.  In particular, check out the `-c` flag.

Answer (score 4):

From your description, it sounds like you're not using the `-c` (compile, but don't link) flag.  Steps to build your project:

1. Compile all of the source files:

   ```
   c++ -c file1.cpp
   c++ -c file2.cpp
   c++ -c file3.cpp
   ```
2. Link your final executable:

   ```
   c++ file1.o file2.o file3.o
   ```

   You can use an optional `-o` flag to specify the output program name.  It probably defaults to `a.out`.

It would be better to use some kind of build tool (like `make`, for example) to automate this process, or you'll find it to be very error prone.